# Replacing Header in php with javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

Im trying to replace `Header()` function in php due to having much problem with it .in firefox is redirecting with no end, and so on. Have also tried to fix this by various posts here with ob_start with no spaces and so on , but nothing fixed it so i want now just replace it by javascript :) .

i have decided to just replace this function by this

```
    if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                $returnurl = $_SESSION['returnurl'] ;
                die("<script> location.href = '<?php echo  $returnurl ;?>'; </script>");
                unset($_SESSION['returnurl']);
                // Logged In!!!!
                return true;
                exit;
            }
```

How ever i didnt get my desired output in the link .

Lets say i have website url like that:

```
    www.mywebsite.com/users/login.php
```

then when using this script im getting this link .

```
  http://www.mywebsite.com/users/<?php echo http://www.mywebsite.com/users/det.php?id=1420481180328&ca=202 ;?>
```

How can this be done and get ride of the first part and get my desired url Thanks.

Comment: Firefox should not have issues with `header()` that other browsers don't have.  Perhaps your URL from `$_SESSION['returnurl']` is somehow not being encoded?  What does Firefox output when you tried using `header()`?

Comment: You should try harder with php header function. There is nothing wrong with it and it's better to make the browser redirect using headers.

Comment: Also, the `die()` function automatically performs an `echo` followed by an `exit`, so any code you have written below the `die()` line will not be executed

Comment: @Manmaru it output nothing just firexo saying its redirecting with no end , and shows nothing.

Comment: @gontrollez have tried it and spent much time on it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong, you can't echo `<?php something ?>` in html and expect it to be interpreted by PHP. It won't.

Try replacing

```
die("<script> location.href = '<?php echo  $returnurl ;?>'; </script>");
```

with

```
die("<script> location.href = '$returnurl'; </script>");
```

Comment: yes this solved the url but its same problem, its getting redirecting with no end :(.